# Better way of getting day of year for a different calendar

Tags: c#, calendar

I'm trying to get the day of month for following calendar:

[image]

I wrote two different functions that accomplish this:

```
public int DayOfYear(int year, int month, int day)
{
 
    var months = new[] {31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31};

    var dayOfYear = day;

    if (month == 1) return dayOfYear;
    for (var i = 0; i < month-1; i++)
    {
        dayOfYear += months[i];
    }

    return  dayOfYear;
}
```

And to do this without a loop:

```
public int DayOfYear(int year, int month, int day)
{
 
    var dayOfYear = day;
        
    if (month <= 5)
        dayOfYear += 31 * (month-1);
    else
        dayOfYear += 31 * 5 + 30 * ((month - 5) - 2);

    if (month == 12)
        dayOfYear += 31;
        
        
    return dayOfYear;
}
```

For the 12th month lets assume it has always 31 days. I feel that there is a beter mathematical way of doing this, but I can't really come up with it.

An example: (522, 12, 14) is the 349th day of the year according to my calendar. This is correct using both functions. And (522, 1, 1) would be the first day of the year.

For some visualization, (522, 5, 18) would be done as following:
`31 + 31 + 31 + 31 + 18`

And (522, 9, 18) as:

`31 + 31 + 31 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 30 + 30 + 18`

Comment: @Charlieface how would that work for my question I want day of year? Also my day in months clearly are different than the Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary of month => total days up until that point.

```cs
private static readonly Dictionary<int, int> TotalDays = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
  [1] = 0,
  [2] = 31,
  [3] = 62,
  [4] = 93,
  // etc
};

// for day of month validation
private static readonly Dictionary<int, int> DaysPerMonth = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
  [1] = 31,
  [2] = 31,
  [3] = 31,
  [4] = 31,
  // etc
};
```

Then calculate the day of year based on the days up to that point plus the day of this month:

```cs
public int DayOfYear(int year, int month, int day)
{
    // validate your parameters 

    if (!TotalDays.TryGetValue(month, out var total)) 
        throw new Exception("invalid month");

    if (day <= 0 || day > DaysPerMonth[month]) 
       throw new Exception("day too big or small");

    return total + day;
}
```

Comment: This a good way, I have also thought of doing this. But since this calendar unlike the Gregorian calendar has repeated same days of month for series of months. I think we can do this mathemathicaly without a dictionary.

Comment: @OS while that may be so, the above is likely **clearer**. A mathematical solution may not be obvious to others reading your code (or even your future self), making it difficult to reason about and read. Remember you write code once but read it many times. If I saw such a solution, including your second example in a PR/code review I would absolutely decline it

Comment: Isn't that what we can use comments for? To help us understand the code better? Calendrical calculations tend to be mathematical in nature.

Answer (score 1):

The one-line solution:

```
public int DayOfYear(int year, int month, int day) =>
   31 * (month - 1) - Math.Max(0, month - 6) + day;
```

It just assumes 31 days in each month before it first. so 31*(month-1), but since at 6th month it's 30 days so we subtract Math.Max(0, month-6), and then simply add the day(s).

It will work for leap years as well, but only for for valid dates.